# Encryption and decryption using an excisting key and Iv

Tags: java, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

I got an encrypting key in HEX format and its intialization vector (HEX), the length of both of them is 32, I got an encrypted phone number from the client side, and I should decrypt it using the same encryption key.
Here is the method:

```
    private static final String key = "*";
    private static final String initVector = "*";
    private static final String characterEncoding       = "UTF-8";
    private static final String cipherTransformation    = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING";
    private static final String aesEncryptionAlgorithem = "AES";
 public static String decrypt(String encryptedText) {
        String decryptedText = "";
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
            byte[] keyByte = key..getBytes(characterEncoding);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyByte, aesEncryptionAlgorithem);
            IvParameterSpec ivparameterspec = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes());
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivparameterspec);
            Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
            byte[] cipherText = decoder.decode(encryptedText.getBytes("UTF8"));
            decryptedText = new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText), "UTF-8");

        } catch (Exception E) {
            System.err.println("decrypt Exception : "+E.getMessage());
        }
        return decryptedText;
    }
```

the length of the given key and Iv is 32, I got this exception:
***Encrypt Exception : Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long***
I think I should convert the key and the Iv to another format in order to have the wanted length.

Comment: The hex decoding of key and IV is missing, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/140861/9014097

Comment: @Topaco You made my day, thank you